# error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -w/--width

Tags: python, argparse

I had a problem: `python` and `Opencv`
I just to trying this script from [Measuring distance between objects in an image with OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/)

```
/Users/Acer/OneDrive/Desktop/contohajaya/distance_between.py
usage: distance_between.py [-h] -i IMAGE -w WIDTH
distance_between.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -w/--width
```

I had `import argparse`

if you have a solution, please write down ya :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to it, could you edit your post and directly enter the code?

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/#comment-450795 this exact question is asked and resolved in the comments on the blog post itself

Comment: error means you have to run it (in console) with arguments `distance_between.py -i path_to_image -w some_width_value`

Comment: How are you calling this script?  From a shell?  From some IDE like sypder?  Do you know what commandline arguments are, and how to provide them?

Answer (score 1):

It is not error but expected result.

You have to run code in console/terminal/cmd.exe/bash/etc. and use arguments

```
 distance_between.py -i path_to_image -w some_width_value
```

You can't run it without arguments because it is useless.

And it means you can't double click script to run it because it will run without arguments.

---

**EDIT:**

You can use `add_argument( default=... )` to use default value when you don't set argument in console - ie. default `width` 800

```
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=float, required=True, default=800, help="...")
```

It can be useful for `width` which probably often will need the same but it can be boring to run code always with the same image.

---

Of course you can remove all `ArgumentParser` and use constant values in code - ie

```
args = {"width": 800, "image": "path/to/image.jpg"}
```

but it will be even more boring to run always for the same image.

To use different image you would have to change this values in code.

With `default=...` in `ArgumentParser` it is much better because you can run without arguments and it will use default values but you can still run with arguments in console to use different values without changing code.

Comment: thank you very much for responding ..... I still want to ask, can it be run without argument? and how? actually I don't know much about arguments

Comment: you can use `default=...` in `add_argument(...)` to set default value and then you can run without arguments in console. But it will use always the same `image` and the same `width`. It can be useful for `width` but using always the same image seem "boring" - it is more useful to run it with different images (using argument in console).